# Bootstrap table: collapse table inside table row

Tags: bootstrap-4, toggle, tablesorter, bootstrap-table

I want to make a collapsable table inside a table row with data-toggle="table" attribute for a main table, because I want it to be sortable. But it creates td that isnt in my HTML code. Because I think it targets both main and inside the row tables? How can I fix this?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3we09xy5/1/

```
 <table
        class="table table-dark table-bordered mt-5"
        id="table"
        data-toggle="table"
        data-target="table"
        data-sortable="true"
      >
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th data-sortable="true">Example</th>
            <th data-sortable="true">Example</th>
            <th data-sortable="true">Example</th>
            <th data-sortable="true">Example</th>
            <th data-sortable="true">Example</th>
            <th data-sortable="true">Example</th>
            <th data-sortable="true">Example</th>
            <th data-sortable="true">Example</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <button
                class="btn btn-light btn-xs"
                data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#demo1"
                class="accordion-toggle"
              >
                <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
              </button>
            </td>
            <td>#757894</td>
            <td>Example</td>
            <td>Example</td>
            <td>Example</td>
            <td>06-07-2018</td>
            <td>Example</td>
            <td>15s</td>
            <td>
              <span class="badge badge-danger">Declined</span>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <td colspan="12" class="hiddenRow">
            <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="demo1">
              <table class="table table-striped table-light">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Example</th>
                    <th>Example</th>
                    <th>Example</th>
                    <th>Example</th>
                    <th>Example</th>
                    <th>Example</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Example</td>
                    <td>Example</td>
                    <td>Example</td>
                    <td>some date</td>
                    <td>some date</td>
                    <td>
                      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i
                      ></a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Comment: can you describe a little more. your question is not cleared.

Comment: You can clearly see the problem in the jsfiddle. There are randomly generated < td > cells that shouldn't exist. If I remove the properties for the main table, everything looks fine. But I want to have attributes, such as sort class. But I don't want to sort the collapsed table. Just the main one.

Comment: just one suggestion, keep the accordian div outside from table.

Comment: It won't work because I don't need it outside the table..